# How to localize a win32 (Non-MFC) DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, localization, mfc

I have few win32 DLL's (Non-MFC) along with individual .rc files for different languages, presently we replace the rc file and build the full DLL again for each locale. 
I am trying to find out a better way of doing it and found that MFC DLL's have something called satellite dll's wherein we can have a single DLL for the code and other resource DLL's for individual rc files. 
But this resource/satellite DLL's solution doesn't seems to be working for Non-MFC dll's.

Could somebody tell me what would be the best way to localize such non-MFC dll's so that we do not need to regenerate the full Dll for each individual locales.

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Comment: You will need to document your Windows version requirements, it is not a detail if XP still needs to be supported.  MUI support for Vista and up is [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721887%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't do the same with non-MFC dlls - I have done so many times.

You just need to create a set of resource-only DLLs, one for each supported language, and (from your main DLL) either load dynamically at runtime, or give them all the same names and just deploy the correct version during installation.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes how to create a resource-only DLL. Although it mentions that it's helpful for MFC, there is no necessity to use MFC at all - you can apply the same logic that MFC uses to decide which satellite to load.

Partial screenshot

[image: MSDN]

Comment: Hi Roger, I already tried it and created a dllNameKOR.dll, but when I put this dll in same folder and try to launch Korean version of my product then I still see english resource strings, which means the runtime is not able to load the resource dll *KOR.dll. I can surely do LoadLibrary, but there are many dialogs in my DLL, and if I do a LoadLibrary solution then I will have to programatically change the captions and size of all the dialog boxes/UI buttons (which I want to avoid by automatic loading)

Comment: @Rahul well you *must* use `LoadLibrary` and you *must* design resources for each language (including dialog templates) - you can't skip that step, even if you use MFC. All MFC does is to handle the `LoadLibrary` on your behalf.

Comment: Hi Roger, I have all the resource and dialog template separate in different rc files. So do you mean that I will have to apply locale specific settings (x,y,width, height, and caption strings) to UI elements through code and MFC will not do it automatically?